# backlight command

Tags: backlight

I bought a laptop recently and installing Loki beta on it.
Every special key works but backlight control, so I want to create a shortcut for it.
Already try with xrandr but doesn't work. I found a solution with xbacklight but it doesn't send notification of the change.

So, my question is, what is the default command to increase and decrease backlight on elementary? I suppose is something with gala or similar, but I can't found myself

Answer (score 1):

I think your keys are working but they aren't detected by the kernel driver, because I have the same problem, for fix that I added the parameter in `/etc/default/grub`

inline `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
add `acpi_backlight=video`
so now it says `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=video"`

then update the grub with `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

I hope this will fix your problem, that `xbacklight` or `xrandr` are legacy don't use that, let the kernel handle that.

Comment: Warning, doing this on Elementary OS 6 made my Sytem unable to boot due to kernel panic: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0). Oddly enough, reinstalling made it work for me.

Comment: @ChecoR I think your problem was another one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cross post from another question I recently answered:

[Cannot change brightness on lock screen](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8361/cannot-change-brightness-on-lock-screen/11748#comment13896_8361)

I make my own brightness hotkeys using xbacklight.

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

After xbacklight is installed:

Go into System Settings
Keyboard
Custom
There is a little plus sign on the bottom right that says "add" when you hover over it.

Make two custom commands

```
xbacklight -inc 8
xbakclight -dec 8
```

Set the keys for these to

(ctrl + (brightness up key))

(ctrl + (brightness down key))

On my laptop I use (ctrl + f5) and (ctrl + f6) for my brightness keys.

What this is done it is possible that you can set your brightness to zero and get no video output. When that happens you will have to press the keys to increase your brightness to get your video back.